# Transfering files greater than 100mb as byte[] array to an asmx webservice

Tags: web-services, asmx, arrays, file-transfer

i am using a 3.5 asp.net webapplication to transer files as byte array to an axmx 1.1 webservice but it gives the following error on invoking the method

"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"

the bytearray length is 120788413 however when i call the same method with a smaller file, i.e. with byte array length 3128994 it works perfectly fine.

Is there a way in the 1.1 asmx webservice to increase the message recieving request length?

the 1.1 webservice cannot be upgraded so cant use WCF have to use the same service, in the webservice i have added this

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="30720" maxRequestLength="1024000"/>
```

in the system.web element

also have added this section

```
<microsoft.web.services2>
        <diagnostics>
      <trace enabled="true" input="InputTrace.webinfo" output="OutputTrace.webinfo"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <messaging>    <maxRequestLength>1024000</maxRequestLength>   </messaging><!-- 1GB -->
    </microsoft.web.services2>
```

but this doesnt seem to work, in my application also i am using httpruntime with the same values

Please guide how can i increase the length of reciveing message in webservice?

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to do this. An ASMX service will copy the entire message in memory several times in the process of handling the request. Your 100MB is at least 300MB in memory.